# problems in installing miktex and texlive

Tags: pdftex, miktex, texlive

I have a problem downloading texlive and miktex, they always direct me to an empty page, is it just me? any suggestions? 
Thanks!

Comment: Did you connect to the download page of [MiKTeX](http://www.miktex.org/download) or [TeX Live](https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html)?

Comment: Welcome! What link are you supplying?

Comment: Yes exactly these links

Answer (score 1):

Try with `ftp`:

- MiKTeX: `ftp://tug.org/tex-archive/systems/windows/miktex/setup/`
- TeX Live: `ftp://tug.org/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet/`

Comment: Haven't FTP support been removed from most browsers nowadays

Comment: @daleif: I don't know, but download managers such as `Filezilla`  have it.